# Update query for wp_posts and wp_postmeta

Tags: wp-query, query, mysql

I had been assuming that `ID` in `wp_posts` is the primary key and that `post_id` in `wp_postmeta` is the foreign key but there is no relationship between them.

How does these two tables relate each other? There is a `meta_key` and `meta_value` column where `meta_key` data are `_sku`, `_price`, and `_stock`. How can I use the `SELECT` or `UPDATE` query on `_sku`, `_price`, `_stock` if they are all in the same column?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description and getting familiar with the built in WP functions as noted below will be invaluable as well.

Answer (score 2):

The `post_id` column in the `wp_postmeta` table *is* a reference to the `ID` column in the `wp_posts` table.

I'd suggest using the native [update_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) function in  WordPress to update the meta data.

E.g. (Post ID is 123 in this example, and we're updating the price to 100.00):

```
update_post_meta(123, '_price', '100.00');
```

Here is the SQL equivalent:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = 100.00
WHERE meta_key like '_price' AND post_id = 123;
```

Comment: Is there any difference in using the WP function vs SQL statement speed wise?

Comment: Generally (for an update) straight SQL won't be any faster. Plus, when you use the API, you get all of the hooks and filters that come along with it. When reading data, the WP API will be faster because you get the benefit of internal caching.

Answer (score 0):

Me ajudou muiiitooo
fiz assim com um exemplo :

```
<?php
```

include 'confi.php';

$post_id = $_POST["post_id"];
$amount_affiliate = $_POST["amount_affiliate"];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value='0.70' WHERE meta_key like 'amount_affiliate' AND post_id='$post_id'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Pedido Com Sucesso";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>

Comment: This answer does not explain anything, it only contains an example query to "postmeta" table.